# How to share scripts among multiple projects?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, shared-libraries, cdn

I have several projects that share files js in my code. 
I do not want to copy common files for each project, I want to share js files.

I don't want to have this created every time for every application.
Is there a way to reference scripts from a central folder in the solution so all projects can share one common script folder with all the scripts common among them? **I thought of a solution to use CDN.**

For example :
project1 
project2
project3
sharefolder

> main.js

Comment: Since your project may not deploy to the same server, you may not share the `main.js` through sharefolder. Try to consider sharing through js nuget package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish that.

1- Using a CDN to upload your js files.

2- Make a [NuGet package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio) from your js files and install it in every project you wish to use them.

3- Reference your js files to other projects using [Add As Link](https://andrewlock.net/including-linked-files-from-outside-the-project-directory-in-asp-net-core/). I think this is what you really want.

Comment: iam add as link but Dont know js files path